# How to programmatically detect package and OS releases on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, apt-get

From bash, what commands would I run to get a boolean value that indicates whether or not there are available package updates or operating system upgrades in Ubuntu?

I know how to run `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` to actually perform the upgrades, but I can't find any easy way to detect when these options are available without using the `--simulate` argument and trying to parse stdout.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
aptitude search '~U'
```

will list all available package updates. You can customize the output format with the `-F` option; [see the manual](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s04s01.html#secDisplayFormat) for details on how.

I'm not aware of any direct equivalent for Ubuntu release updates.

(Relatedly, though, `apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to a newer release. It's the same concept as `upgrade`, just a little more aggressive about dealing with changing dependencies.)

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing my question in Google lead me to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49958/how-to-find-the-number-of-packages-needing-update-from-the-command-line) that lists the command simply as:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
```